# WPF class library, loading XAML with absolute URI or relative URI both not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri

I'm programming a WPF class library mainly based on C# code and I'm currently trying to load XAML file only for styling UI Elements.

Here is the XAML "style" code with "BuildAction : Content" :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="53" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="130" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="99,71,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value= "Top" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE75959" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
</Style>
```

Here is the code for my label :

```
    private void CreateElement(int i)
    {
        UIElementOut[i] = new Label();
        var uiElement = (Label)UIElementOut[i];
        uiElement.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        uiElement.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        uiElement.FontFamily = new FontFamily(FFontInput[i]);
        uiElement.FontSize = Convert.ToDouble(FontSizeIn[i]);
        uiElement.Content = TextIn[i];
        Brush BgBrushColor = new SolidColorBrush(RGBAToMediaColor(FBgCol[i]));
        Brush FgBrushColor = new SolidColorBrush(RGBAToMediaColor(FFgCol[i]));
        uiElement.Background = BgBrushColor;
        uiElement.Foreground = FgBrushColor;

        Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/WpfApplication1/Styles/LabelStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetContentStream(uri);
        System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader reader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();
        ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
        Style myLabelStyle = myResourceDictionary["LabelStyle"] as Style;
        uiElement.Style = myLabelStyle;
    }
```

if UriKind is set to "Relative" I get this error message :

```
A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.
```

But if Urikind is set to "Absolute" then I get this one :

```
Cannot use absolute URI.
```

So in both anyway, XAML file is not loaded and style is not applied.

EDIT :

I tried this URI :

```
pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Styles/LabelStyle.xaml
```

And get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Correct format to reference resourcefile located in a subfolder of the local assembly's project folder

```
pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml
```

Correct format to reference resourcefile in separate referenced assembly is

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml
```

Changing your uri to

```
pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Styles/LabelStyle.xaml
```

should solve the issue

Comment: Read about pack URI scheme : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I tried this already as I found a post which gave a similar answer but I still got the same error.

Comment: Your ResourceDictionary is in same project or another one which you are referencing here ?

Comment: The style folder containing LabelStyle.xaml is right next to my builded .dll which is now in :   Desktop\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\bin\x86\Debug

Comment: With what you have said in your comment, your Style1 folder is in your working directory and you are not using/referecing any outside assembly using Add Reference option in your Project, so pack://application:,,,/Styles/LabelStyle.xaml should work, and use UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute.

Comment: Ok I just found that this line of code 'code'ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;  is creating the problem...

Comment: Check if proper uri scheme is necessary or not ?

Comment: What do you mean proper Uri ?

Comment: Is your Uri which you used in your code working properly ?